# C# Http WebRequest JSON

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm new to WebRequests and I tried this:

```
string json = @"{""Gebruikersnaam"":""user"",""Wachtwoord"":""pass"",""IngelogdBlijven"":true}";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://pontessg.magister.net/api/sessies");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(json.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.Read();
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {


            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

My code is keep returning me ERROR (400) and I don't really know why I think I forgot something, but I don't know what

(The Headers)

```
Request URL:https://pontessg.magister.net/api/sessies
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[...]
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Date: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 21:45:33 GMT
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=[...]
Request Headers
view parsed
POST /api/sessies HTTP/1.1
Host: pontessg.magister.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 88
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-API-Client-ID: 12D8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Origin: https://pontessg.magister.net
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://pontessg.magister.net/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SESSION_ID=[...]; M6UserName=user; username=pass;     Magister.UserName=user; [...]
Request Payload

{"Gebruikersnaam":"user","Wachtwoord":"pass","IngelogdBlijven":true}
```

When I try the JS code below in the console of my browser, it returns 200 OK

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://pontessg.magister.net/api/sessies",
type: "POST",
data: "{\"Gebruikersnaam\":\"user\",\"Wachtwoord\":\"pass\",\"IngelogdBlijven\":true}",
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
success: action_Succeeded,
error: action_Failed
});

function action_Succeeded(r) {
console.log("succes");
}

function action_Failed(r1, r2, r3) {
alert("fail");
}
```

If someone could help me with this, I would like that

Comment: I guess that you need to provide some sort of authentication to the server like using the Cookie header. The reason why your code works in the browser is probably because you are already logged into the website and have a valid cookie that gets sent along with the request. You will also need to provide such cookie when making the request from your .NET application.

Comment: Gebruikersnaam is userame and Wachtwoord is Password

Comment: But how do I add a Cookie Conatainer?